# Min-max the component-wise sum of two sets

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, optimization

When I was trying to prove a problem at hand to be NP-complete, I coined the following problem:

> Given two integer sets $A = \{ a_1, \cdots, a_n \}$ and $B = \{ b_1, \cdots, b_n \}$.
>   We know that there are $n!$ bijections between $A$ and $B$. 
>   For a bijection $f\colon A \to B$, define 
>   $$\max f = \max_{a \in A} \{ a + f(a) \}.$$
>   This problem is to find a bijection which minimizes $\max f$.

I think it is polynomial solvable (which is thus of no use in reduction).
The algorithm is simple: Sort $A$ non-decreasingly and $B$ non-increasingly and map $A$ to $B$ component-wisely.

However, I could not find a proof.

*Problem:* How to prove (or disprove) this algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be an optimal solution in which $f(a_1) < f(a_2)$ for some $a_1 < a_2$. Let $g$ be obtained from $f$ by switching the values at $a_1$ and $a_2$:
$$
g(a) = \begin{cases} f(a_2) & a = a_1, \\ f(a_1) & a = a_2, \\ f(a) & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
a_1 + g(a_1) &= a_1 + f(a_2) < a_2 + f(a_2), \\
a_2 + g(a_2) &= a_2 + f(a_1) < a_2 + f(a_2), \\
a + g(a) &= a + f(a) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{align*}
$$
It follows that $\max g \leq \max f$.

Consider now $f$ as a permutation on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$: the first element is the index of $f(a_n)$, the second element is the index of $f(a_{n-1})$, and so on. It is a classical result that $f$ can be sorted by transposing pairs of numbers in the wrong order, an operation which corresponds to the transformation above (one way is to put $n,n-1,\ldots,2$ in their right place, if needed, in this order). The correctness of your algorithm immediately follows.

Comment: This sort of analysis is very reminiscent of the analysis of greedy algorithms.

Comment: Something isn't right? His proposed optimal bijection $f$ is basically [monotonically decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), thus the property in first sentence should be: $$x \leq y \implies f(x) \geq f(y)$$

Comment: @Billiska I'm assuming for simplicity that the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are distinct, which is implied by the OP's set notation.

Comment: Yes, I think we are on the same page about set $A$ and $B$ being different. A valid solution must be a bijection $f: A \rightarrow B$. In addition, the proposed best solution also have the  property $$x \leq y \implies f(x) \geq f(y)$$ for all $x,y \in A$ however you seem to have the relation the other way round and say $$x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$$ instead. That's why wonder if there is something wrong.

Comment: @Billiska We have the same condition in mind. What you quote is its negation.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. Proof by contradiction. The first sentence assume  the best solution has the negation of property. Then proceeds to show a contradiction that there exist $g$ as better solution. Thus proving the best solution must have the property.

Comment: It's not proof by contradiction, since there is no contradiction. There could be other solutions which are also optimal. Instead, what I show is that you can transform every solution to the one produced by algorithm without making it any worse.

Comment: Thanks. Is the paragraph starting with "Consider now"  another proof? I do not quite understand it (I understand the argument in preceding paragraphs). Specifically, I understand all sentences in this paragraph but the last one "The correctness of your algorithm immediately follows".  What is the logic behind it? Does it mean that the actual values of $a_i$ do not matter (thus we can only consider $\{ 1, \cdots n\}$)?

Comment: @hengxin There's only one proof. First we have a lemma, and then the proof itself. The values of the $a_i$ do matter, but for your algorithm only their relative order does, and the proof reflects this. I encourage you to think of the last sentence as a riddle - once you manage to understand it, all will fall into place.

Comment: The lemma deals with a single "inversion". The next paragraph argues that we could obtain $f$ from any optimal solution by iteratively applying this lemma. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @hengxin Yes, that's the structure of the proof.

Answer (score 2):

I come up with another proof and answer my question.

Denote the bijection produced by this algorithm by $f$. We prove that $f$ is optimal.

Suppose that $a + f(a)$ is maximal for $f$ and consider any bijection $g$ other than $f$. We need to prove that $\max g \ge \max\,f$ (see the figure below).

- CASE 1: If $g(a) \ge f(a)$, then $\max g \ge \max\,f$.
- CASE 2: $b = g(a) < f(a)$. Consider $b' = f^{-1}(b)$. We have $b' > a$.

  - CASE 2.1: $c = g(f(b')) \ge f(a)$, then $\max g \ge \max\,f$.
  - CASE 2.2: $c = g(f(b')) < f(a)$. Consider $c' = f^{-1}(c)$. We have $c' > a$.

Continue the argument above. We eventually identify some $u \in A (u > a)$ with $g(u) \ge f(a)$ since the number of elements larger than $a$ in $A$ equals the number of elements smaller than $f(a)$ in $B$. Thus we have $\max g < \max\,f$.

[image: minmax-componentwise-setsum]